# jQuery function not stopping execution

Tags: jquery, function, return

i am trying to validate a form before adding the visitor info to a mysql db. The jQuery script follows:

```
var phone = $("input#phone").val();
    if (phone == "") {
  $("label#phone_error").show();
  $("input#phone").focus();
  return false;
}

//Captcha validation
var security_code = $("input#security_code").val();
$.ajaxSetup({cache: false})
$.get('getsession.php', {requested: 'seccode'}, function (data) {
var session = data;

if (security_code !== session) {
    $("label#security_code_error").show();
    $("input#security_code").focus();
    alert ('NO MATCH: '+security_code+' '+session);
    return false; // <= FUNCTION SHOULD EXIT HERE
} else {
    alert ('MATCH!!!: '+security_code+' '+session);
}
});     

    var dataString = 'name='+ name + '&email=' + email + '&phone=' + phone;
    //alert (dataString);return false;

    $.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "bin/process.php",
  data: dataString,
  success: function() {
    $('#contact_form').html("<div id='message'></div>");
    $('#message').html("<h2>Contact Form Submitted!</h2>")
    .append("<p>We will be in touch soon.</p>")
    .hide()
    .fadeIn(1500, function() {
      $('#message').append("<img id='checkmark' src='images/check.png' />");
    });
  }
 });
return false;
});
});
```

If a name is missing, then the form displays an error and focus the field to be completed. The problem is the captcha validation. If it matches, the form is successfully processed and the lead gets added to the DB, however, if the security code entered in a text filed does not match the generated code, the error is displayed but the form info is still added to the DB. Looks like the "return false; // <= FUNCTION SHOULD EXIT HERE" is not recognized.
Any suggestion on what is wrong with my code?

Comment: Unrelated to the question, but doing things like `input#phone` can actually be slower than just `#phone`.  `id` lookup is very fast, no need to make jquery validate that it is also an `input` unless that check is really needed.

Comment: Thank you James, I'll modify the code based on your suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `return false` that you expect to end your execution is in the callback function for an AJAX request. The first A in AJAX stands for asynchronous, so that function isn't executed until the request returns a successful response.

However, since it *is* asynchronous, the rest of the function making that AJAX request will still execute, therefore submitting a separate AJAX POST request to submit the form data, completely unrelated to the first AJAX call.

What you need to do is move the below part of your code into the callback function for the AJAX request that checks the captcha, and only execute it if the validation was successful.

```
var dataString = 'name=' + name + '&email=' + email + '&phone=' + phone;
//alert (dataString);return false;
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "bin/process.php",
    data: dataString,
    success: function() {
        $('#contact_form').html("<div id='message'></div>");
        $('#message').html("<h2>Contact Form Submitted!</h2>").append("<p>We will be in touch soon.</p>").hide().fadeIn(1500, function() {
            $('#message').append("<img id='checkmark' src='images/check.png' />");
        });
    }
});
```

The entire code would look like this:

```
var phone = $("input#phone").val();
if (phone == "") {
    $("label#phone_error").show();
    $("input#phone").focus();
    return false;
}

//Captcha validation
var security_code = $("input#security_code").val();
$.ajaxSetup({
    cache: false
})
$.get('getsession.php', {
    requested: 'seccode'
}, function(data) {
    var session = data;

    if (security_code !== session) {
        $("label#security_code_error").show();
        $("input#security_code").focus();
        alert('NO MATCH: ' + security_code + ' ' + session);
        return false; // <= FUNCTION SHOULD EXIT HERE
    } else {
        alert('MATCH!!!: ' + security_code + ' ' + session);
        // successful, so let's submit the details
        var dataString = 'name=' + name + '&email=' + email + '&phone=' + phone;
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "bin/process.php",
            data: dataString,
            success: function() {
                $('#contact_form').html("<div id='message'></div>");
                $('#message').html("<h2>Contact Form Submitted!</h2>").append("<p>We will be in touch soon.</p>").hide().fadeIn(1500, function() {
                    $('#message').append("<img id='checkmark' src='images/check.png' />");
                });
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you Anthony. At first I saw your explanation and manage to understand the asynchronous operation of AJAX. Then included the rest of the code inside the if statement. After a while checked this page again and voila, the code is the same. Thank you, I understood a lot from this.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

> var phone = $("input#phone").val();
>       if (phone == "") {
>           $("label#phone_error").show();
>           $("input#phone").focus();
>           return false;
>       }
>
> ```
> //Captcha validation
> var security_code = $("input#security_code").val();
> $.ajaxSetup({cache: false})
> $.get('getsession.php', { requested: 'seccode' }, function(data) {
>     var session = data;
>
>     if (security_code !== session) {
>         $("label#security_code_error").show();
>         $("input#security_code").focus();
>         alert('NO MATCH: ' + security_code + ' ' + session);
>     } else {
>         alert('MATCH!!!: ' + security_code + ' ' + session);
>         var dataString = 'name='+ name + '&email=' + email + '&phone=' + phone;
>         $.ajax({
>             type: "POST",
>             url: "bin/process.php",
>             data: dataString,
>             success: function() {
>                 $('#contact_form').html("<div id='message'></div>");
>                 $('#message').html("<h2>Contact Form Submitted!</h2>")
>                     .append("<p>We will be in touch soon.</p>")
>                     .hide()
>                     .fadeIn(1500, function() {
>                         $('#message').append("<img id='checkmark' src='images/check.png' />");
>                     });
>             }
>         });
>     }
> });
> ```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `return` outside a function.

Comment: The `return` statements all appear to be in valid locations, assuming that the last few lines of code are the end of a jQuery event handler binding.

Comment: czahor is correct, although I suspect that the OP has ommitted the start of their function and not the end of it. The return statement within the AJAX callback is meaningless, return false; // <= FUNCTION SHOULD EXIT HERE